# filter type : bypass or by pass

Tags: electronic-filters, digital-communication

I am not an expert in the signal processing!

I working on a simulation the interpolation ( upsampling and filter). The interpolation process was divided into two stages:

- stage 1: FIR - filter ( upsampling factor N) and "bypass" ( factor 1)
- stage 2: FIR - filters and "bypass" ( factor 1)

Could someone explain what bypass filter is?